# Is there a shorthand way of doing a @media query OR a custom class?

Tags: css

I have a sidebar on my website that collapses into a narrower one on a smaller screen. I would like to add an option now, to be able to toggle having the narrower sidebar, even if you're on a big screen. Let's say that i do it by adding the class `.compact` to `<body>`.

My CSS for the compact sidebar was originally inside a `@media` block:

```css
    @media(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
        nav {}
        nav > .nav-item {}
        /* ... */
    }
```

And would now also need to be as children of `.compact`:

```css
    body.compact nav {}
    body.compact nav > .nav-item {}
    /* ... */
```

Which would need me to copy/paste all of the declarations to achieve that behaviour, since `@media`'s syntax is one of a wrapper, and cannot be a sibling of `.compact`'s declarations.

Is there a different clever way that this can be achieved, that does NOT involve javascript?

Comment: You could eliminate your media query block altogether and add `compact` class to your body on page load and remove the option to toggle the view if it is a mobile. In this way you won't have redundant styles. I see no harm in writing a line or two of JavaScript to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using [css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*):

```js
function toggleSidebar(size) {
  let container = document.getElementById("container");
  let sibebarClass;

  switch (size) {
    case 'sm':
      sidebarClass = 'small-sidebar';
      break;
    case 'md':
      sidebarClass = 'medium-sidebar';
      break;
    case 'lg':
      sidebarClass = 'large-sidebar';
      break;
    default:
      sidebarClass = '';

  }

  container.classList.remove('large-sidebar', 'medium-sidebar', 'small-sidebar');
  container.classList.add(sidebarClass);

}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.page-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  /* This will be default value */
  --sidebar-width: 300px;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Sidebar width is defined in this block */
.page-container.large-sidebar {
  --sidebar-width: 400px;
}
.page-container.medium-sidebar {
  --sidebar-width: 300px;
}
.page-container.small-sidebar {
  --sidebar-width: 200px;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: var(--sidebar-width);
  background-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="page-container">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <button class="toggleSidebar" onclick="toggleSidebar('sm');">Toggle small</button>
    <button class="toggleSidebar" onclick="toggleSidebar('md');">Toggle medium</button>
    <button class="toggleSidebar" onclick="toggleSidebar('lg');">Toggle large</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way you only need to add new `.page-container.somesize-sidebar` to add new sidebar size without touching `.sidebar` selector.

If you want different sidebar sizes for different screens - you can put `.page-container.small-sidebar` and others inside `@media` query.